# Trigger.io parse push, subscribe to multiple channels

Tags: javascript, trigger.io, parse-platform

Is it possible for a client, written in javascript, to subscribe to multiple parse channels, either by doing multiple calls to parse.subscribe, or by supplying multiple channels, to a single parse.subscribe channel request

Thanks all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can just call subscribe multiple times, there is also a subscribedChannels api to list all channels subscribed to: http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/partners/parse.html#push-subscribedchannels